Does it make sense to offer only 512-bit hash in a post-quantum DSS?
In the currently defined OIDs for ML-DSA, only SHA-512 are specified. I wondered why there's no SHA-256 (or even SHA-384), I thought quantum computers' degrade their security, so no point offering them in a post-quantum DSS anyway.
Does this thinking make sense?

Maybe they thought that there would be little need for other hash functions in practice. FIPS 204 does specify SHA-256 and SHAKE128 in 5.4.1 which means that the security argument goes out of the window. In principle I'm all for not allowing every possible combination (as we would get HSM's that all implement slightly different functions, as is already the case for KDF's). That said, SHA-256 makes sense for lower security levels because of the support in hardware and embedded devices.

It's a bit of an oddity, but I think it arise mostly out of a desire not to issue OIDs willy-nilly. As Maarten notes in his comment, FIPS 204 does give SHA256 and SHAKE128 (with 256-bit output length) as possible options. They also state in section 5.4 that digest must be produced by...

an approved hash function or XOF (e.g., from FIPS 180 [8] or FIPS 202 [7]) that provides at least  bits of classical security strength against both collision and second preimage attacks

as such then OIDs for id-hash-ml-dsa-65-with-sha256, id-hash-ml-dsa-65-with-shake128, id-hash-ml-dsa-87-with-sha256, and id-hash-ml-dsa-87-with-shake128 would not be appropriate. Possibly they might have considered id-hash-ml-dsa-65-with-sha384 or id-hash-ml-dsa-87-shake256/512, but as these are not included as examples in FIPS 204, perhaps they did not think that it was clear that such an OID would see much use?
Arguably, they could have included id-hash-ml-dsa-44-with-sha256 and id-hash-ml-dsa-44-with-shake128/256, but I've noticed a bit of reluctance to use ml-dsa-44, with people replacing/hybridising 256-bit ECDSA with ml-dsa-65 (instead of the intended 128-bit security equivalent ml-dsa-44). This may be due to the advice of the pq-crystals site who state

We recommend using the Dilithium3 parameter set, which—according to a very conservative analysis—achieves more than 128 bits of security against all known classical and quantum attacks.

the reluctance to use ml-dsa-44 may in turn have led to a reluctance to issue too many OIDs involving that parameter set.
